# How to scan through tensor not at dimension 0?

Tags: python, tensorflow

The tensorflow document states that tf.scan scans on the list of tensors unpacked from elems on dimension 0.
The simplest version of scan repeatedly applies the callable fn to a sequence of elements from first to last. The elements are made of the tensors unpacked from elems on dimension 0.

My question is:
How to scan on the list of tensors on other dimension instead of dimension 0?
For example, 
I have a tensor, ref, defined as below.

```
>>> ref = tf.Variable(tf.ones([2,3,3],tf.int32))
....
>>> print(ref.eval())
[[[1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]]

 [[1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]]]
```

I want to scan through the ref[1,0], ref[1,1], ref[1,2] and apply a function to each of the, ,say add 1.
That is to say, I want ref be after the operation

```
>>> print(ref.eval())
[[[1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]
  [1 1 1]]

 [[2 2 2]
  [2 2 2]
  [2 2 2]]]
```

Can I use tf.scan to do that? If yes, how?
If not, any how to do in other way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`tf.transpose()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose) your tensor before the [`tf.scan()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scan) and transpose back after.

Also, if you want the variable `ref` to contain the new value after the operation, you need to [`tf.assign()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) the value back.

Please note your desired example value is achieved just by applying a straight-up scan, with no transpose, however. Refer to this code (tested) (see another example with transpose at the bottom of answer):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

ref = tf.Variable(tf.ones([2,3,3],tf.int32))
ref2 = tf.scan( lambda y, x: x + 1, ref )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
    print ( sess.run( ref2 ) ) # ref2 is calculated
    print ( "====================")
    print ( sess.run( ref ) ) # the original ref is unchanged
    print ( "====================")
    sess.run( tf.assign( ref, ref2 ) ) # assign the value back to ref
    print ( sess.run( ref ) )
```

outputs:

> [[[1 1 1]
>     [1 1 1]
>     [1 1 1]]
>
> [[2 2 2]
>     [2 2 2]
>     [2 2 2]]]
>    ====================
>   [[[1 1 1]
>     [1 1 1]
>     [1 1 1]]
>
> [[1 1 1]
>     [1 1 1]
>     [1 1 1]]]
>    ====================
>   [[[1 1 1]
>     [1 1 1]
>     [1 1 1]]
>
> [[2 2 2]
>     [2 2 2]
>     [2 2 2]]]

If you use [`tf.transpose()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose), you can achieve a scan along any dimension:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

ref = tf.Variable(tf.ones([2,3,3],tf.int32))
ref2 = tf.transpose( tf.scan( lambda y, x: x + 1,
                              tf.transpose( ref, [ 1, 0, 2 ] ) ),
                     [ 1, 0, 2 ] )

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run( tf.global_variables_initializer() )
    sess.run( tf.assign( ref, ref2 ) )
    print ( sess.run( ref ) )
```

will output:

> [[[1 1 1]
>     [2 2 2]
>     [2 2 2]]
>
> [[1 1 1]
>     [2 2 2]
>     [2 2 2]]]